# Responding to GET /favicon.ico request does not show the browser tab icon

Tags: html, http, favicon

I have a webserver since my main HTML page does not contain a webicon, (just a basic template)

```
  "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  Content-Type: text/html
  Connection: close
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <h1>This is a heading</h1>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Both chrome and Mozilla will also send an additional HTTP request :

```
GET /favicon.ico
```

I would like to respond to this request by sending a PNG file, problem is the tab icon is not showing up even If I successfully return to the /favicon.ico request.

Ny response to GET /favicon.ico looks like this:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: text/plain
  Connection: close

  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAB0CAYAAABzNJfPAAAABGdBTUEAALGP....
```

But the icon does not show up on the tab bar. I am getting this:

[image]

What I was expecting is for the icon to show up in the tab like this

[image]

You might say just include the icon in the main HTML. But that would be "cheating" since what I am setting out to do is to handle a /favicon.ico requests from browsers. If I do that I would just be avoiding the issue, not addressing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your content-type header is set to text/plain which makes the browser read it as plain text, not an image. Try setting it to image/png. Also, don't send the image as base64, just send the raw image. I'm not sure what web server you are using so I can't help you with how to send it as a raw image.

Comment: Or `image/x-icon` for `.ico` image file formats. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29.

Comment: Changing the content type did not work, both chrome and mozilla did not show the tab icon. if not base64 what would the format be ? need to know what the format is so i can use converters online :D

Comment: @DrakeJest What type of server are you using